# how to tell if user is running first time or updating app

Tags: android, migration, version

I have an app where users are on version X. When releasing version X+1 I want to tell
if a user is running the app for the first time or if he used to be in X and is updating to X+1.

Comment: Why do you want to know this?  There might be a better approach.

Comment: @Simon what would you propose, then?

Comment: I don't know.   You still haven't told us what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `SharedPreferences` and holding the current version in there. Every time the user starts up the app you check if the current version is different than the version you saved in shared preferences.

for example

```
String appVer = "";
try {
        appVer = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }

if(!pref.getString(Preferences.LAST_VER_CHK, "").equals(appVer)){
    //update preferences to new version
    //do whatever you want to do on the update
}
```

this is the way I use, not sure if there is another way or not

Comment: the default value for pref.getString should be something that is never going to be a version number, as you'd want to know that the application was launched for the first time (or, appVer, if you don't want to know).

Comment: @njzk2 yes i just pulled this directly from my code where I was looking for a specific previous version and didnt have this sharedpreference stored before